# error running javafx application with Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a javafx program that I was formerly developing in sublime text before migrating to intellij as my editing environment. As of now, **I can compile and run without error through the command line** (Windows). However, when I try to run it from intellij, I get the following message:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/868693306.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
at Main.setNewScene(Main.java:40)
at Main.start(Main.java:29)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/2069914884.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/646648017.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1106256089.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/151108218.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/2004449016.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You are getting this error because the FXMLoader is not able to load the fxml file. Most probably, your IDE doesn't recognize the directory, in which the fxmls are present, as a resource directory. Adding details about your project structure and how you run it through cmd may help us to debug the problem for you.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha the FXML files are in the same directory as the class files. There are also no package declarations, meaning that EVERYTHING is in the same single directory.

Comment: Are you sure that the fxml files are in the same directory as the class files? or is just the java files? Make sure the directory which holds the java and fxml files is marked as the source. If that doesn't solve it, add the code which you are using the to load the fxml file and also the directory structure of your project.

Comment: @itachiUchiha Everything, java files, class files, fxml files, an everything else is in the same directory. It's a very tiny project, so it made sense at the time to put it all in one folder for simplicity's sake. The folder itself is also marked as the source.

Comment: Your .java files are in the same directory as your .class files? That just doesn't sound right. I don't use IntelliJ but any other IDE I've used would need quite a bit of configuration to allow that to happen. Can you edit your post to show your project structure, as @ItachiUchiha asked?

Comment: @James_D As I said, I started this project with sublime text. I created all the java files in one folder and when I needed to compile, I typed this in the command line: 'javac *.java' and 'java Main' to run it. Everything was all in the same folder before I moved to Intellij. When I opened it in intellij and tried to compile/run, it gave me that.

Comment: I suspect IntelliJ has created a new set of class files then, though I am not certain. I would just open a file browser and have a look at what's in the IntelliJ project...

Comment: @James_D You're missing the point. When I hit run in intellij, it should compile first and then run those class files, wherever they might be. The class files' location doesn't matter in that aspect. The point is, intellij could not compile AT ALL what the command line could.

Comment: @WillRosser You're not making any sense. The stack trace you posted is a runtime error: if it didn't compile, you wouldn't see a runtime error as there would be nothing to run. You haven't posted any code (why not??) so we have to guess, but my best guess is that the error (line 40 of Main.java) is something like `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(...))`. That is an instruction to load the FXML file ***from the same location as the class file***. So the location of the class file (or the location of the FXML file relative to it) is extremely important for that to succeed.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, otherwise voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: @Jame_D Never mind. I solved it by myself. It turns out that intellij had miss-defined the source folder and by reloading the folder as a new project, I was able to fix the problem. There was nothing wrong with the code itself (AS I SAID REPEATEDLY) - it was always intellij that was the problem.

Comment: It was your project setup that was the problem. People have been telling you this in this thread for 4 days. I was asking for code because it would have given me the opportunity to show you how to add some logging that would have helped diagnose the issue. Perhaps in future you will get help more quickly by providing the information people (who are trying to help you, for free) ask for, instead of arguing with them and SHOUTING at them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be intellij having an issue with the source folder in the project directory. By moving all my java files to a new directory and reopening it in intellij as a new project with a single, correct source folder, the problem completely went away.

(As stated in the question, the code itself was functional and worked through the command line.)